# Does $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(2^{1-x!}3^{1-x!!}4^{1-x!!!}5^{1-x!!!!}6^{1-x!!!!!}\cdot\cdot\cdot\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=L$ admits a closed form?

Tags: limits, closed-form, gamma-function

I try to simplify this limit :

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(2^{1-x!}3^{1-x!!}4^{1-x!!!}5^{1-x!!!!}6^{1-x!!!!!}\cdots\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=L$$

Where we compose the Gamma function with  itself .

From the past I already know that it involves Euler-Mascheroni constant (derivative of the Gamma function near zero) and it converges .

Interestingly it involves power of prime numbers and perhaps some number theory .

For example :

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln\left(2^{\left(1-x!\right)}3^{\left(1-\left(x!\right)!\right)}\right)}{x}=\gamma(-\gamma\ln(3)+\ln(6))$$

See also the case [n=5](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%20ln%28%28%282%5E%281-%28%28x%21%29%29%29*3%5E%281-%28x%21%29%21%29*4%5E%281-%28%28x%21%29%21%29%21%29%285%29%5E%281-%28%28%28%28x%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%29%29%29%5E%281%2Fx%29%29%20at%20x%3D0) and [n=7](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit%20ln%28%28%282%5E%281-%28%28x%21%29%29%29*3%5E%281-%28x%21%29%21%29*4%5E%281-%28%28x%21%29%21%29%21%29%285%29%5E%281-%28%28%28%28x%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%29%286%29%5E%281-%28%28%28%28%28x%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%29%287%29%5E%281-%28%28%28%28%28%28x%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%21%29%29%21%29%29%29%5E%281%2Fx%29%29%20at%20x%3D0)

How to simplify it or in other word does L admits a closed form ?

Comment: It involves powers of all the naturals not just the primes.

Comment: @FShrike Well I want to simplify so I use prime number .

Comment: Expecting that thing to have a closed form is the most extreme form of optimism I have seen in a long time...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez we will see how it goes.

Comment: Use `\cdots` instead of `\cdot\cdot\cdot`

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks you for the edit .

Comment: Yes, there is $L=e^{\text{Eitas}}$ involving this very particular constant (have a look at the name of the UFO's as given by NASA)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Is it [this](https://archive.org/stream/NASA_NTRS_Archive_19700022692/NASA_NTRS_Archive_19700022692_djvu.txt) since it contains the word “eitas”? If so, there are too many numbers in the link to know which you mean. Can you link to it?

Comment: @TymaGaidash. This uses the most basic cryptography I used when I was 4 or 5. I cannot open the link. Cheers :-)

Comment: I have the feelings this is strange. @ClaudeLeibovici you are a so funny guy .Far sure.Twin of Word obviously.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici if you know Tolkien i propose $L=e^{golas}$

Comment: Here is the closed form expression.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez. Funny but there is one

Comment: I  added some material in my answer. What is very interesting is the most general case where $k$ is a continuous variable.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B-%28EulerGamma*Derivative%5B0%2C+1%2C+0%5D%5BLerchPhi%5D%5B1+-+EulerGamma%2C+0%2C+++++2+%2B+k%5D%29%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C100%7D%5D

Comment: If the above link does not work, just type  `Plot[-(EulerGamma*Derivative[0, 1, 0][LerchPhi][1 - EulerGamma, 0,   2 + k]),{k,0,100}]`

Comment: The continuous function is fascinating. Use the WA syntax with `{k,-5,100}` . What that does mean with regard to the discrete case ? Do you think that you could add this plot in my answer ? Thanks & cheers

Comment: The exponential of the input gives an absolute value like [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5Bexp%28-%28EulerGamma*Derivative%5B0%2C+1%2C+0%5D%5BLerchPhi%5D%5B1+-+EulerGamma%2C+0%2C+++2+%2B+k%5D%29%29%2C%7Bk%2C-50%2C100%7D%5D+)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The calculations are not so complicated as I thought.

Let
$$t_1=x \qquad \text{and} \qquad t_n=[t_{n-1}]!\qquad \text{and} \qquad u_n=\frac 1x \,\log \left(n^{1-t_n}\right)$$ Using series expansion around $x=0$ gives at the limit
$$u_n=\gamma\,(1 -\gamma)^{n-2}\, \log(n)$$
Then, the partial sum of the logarithm of the expression is
$$S_p=\gamma \sum_{n=2}^p (1 -\gamma)^{n-2}\, \log(n)$$

There is an explicit result for the partial sum
$$\color{blue}{S_p=\gamma  (1-\gamma )^{p-1} \Phi^{(0,1,0)}(1-\gamma
   ,0,p+1)-\gamma  \Phi^{(0,1,0)}(1-\gamma ,0,2)}$$ where $\Phi(.)$ is the Lerch transcendent function.

$$\large \color{red}{\log(L)=\underset{p\to \infty }{\text{limit }}S_p=-\gamma \, \Phi^{(0,1,0)}(1-\gamma ,0,2)}$$

which is also
$$\large \color{red}{\log(L)=-\frac{\gamma }{(1-\gamma )^2}\,\,\,\text{Li}^{(1,0)}_0(1-\gamma )}$$

Numerically,
$$\log(L)=0.941986151767766605347692845869094706057514927\cdots$$

$$\text{Li}^{(1,0)}_0(1-\gamma )=-0.291705209103709537352092057571457\cdots$$

**Edit**

Making the problem more general
$$t_1=x \qquad \text{and} \qquad t_n=[t_{n-1}]!\qquad \text{and} \qquad u_n=\frac 1x \,\log \left((n+k)^{1-t_n}\right)$$
$$\large \color{red}{\log\big[L(k)\big]=-\gamma \, \Phi^{(0,1,0)}(1-\gamma ,0,2+k)}$$ which is valid for any $k>0$.

This is a very nice function of $k$.

If $k$ is an integer $(k>0)$, the limit can also write in terms of the derivative of the polylogarithm function
$$\large \color{red}{\log(L_k)=-\frac{\gamma}{ (1-\gamma )^{k+2}}\,\Bigg[\text{Li}^{(1,0)}_0(1-\gamma )+\sum_{i=2}^{k+1} (1-\gamma )^i\log(i)  \Bigg]}$$

**Update**

As a continuous function
$$L(k)=\exp\left(-\gamma \,\, \Phi^{(0,1,0)}(1-\gamma ,0,2+k) \right)$$ is extrely strange : it is perfectly continuous for $k \geq -2$ and it still exists for $k<-2$ with discontinuities at each negative integer values of $k$. Between two negative integer numbers $(-6 \leq k \leq -3)$, it goes through a maximum. For $k <-6$, the function starts to be continuous again.

What is curious is the approximation
$$L(k) \sim k+10 \gamma  \left(e^{\gamma }-\text{Ei}(1) \log (2)\right)$$

Comment: Only one comment  https://youtu.be/-3GwqpxVSZI

Comment: @ErikSatie. Just wait : I have better for you !

Comment: @ErikSatie. Prove that, if $k$ is the positive root of  $12011 x^2-765 x-145=0$, then $\log\big[L(k)\big] >1$. Just for your eyes, the difference is $5.65\times 10^{-14}$

Comment: Worth let $L$ as above then define : $$f(x)=\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\ln\left(L\right)a^{-x}+\frac{1}{2}!\right)+\frac{1}{4}\right)!+\frac{1}{8}\right)!+\frac{1}{16}\right)!+\frac{1}{32}\right)!+\frac{1}{64}\right)!$$ then $$\left(f\left(x\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}>\frac{\sqrt{2\pi x}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{x}e^{\frac{1}{12x}}}{x!},a=e$$ Again thanks for the helps it was funny .

Comment: @ErikSatie. More than funny : it was very interesting ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It is still confusing: how is Eitas$=\operatorname{Li}_0^{(0,1)}(1-\gamma)$? There is as if nothing exactly about it online

Comment: @TymaGaidash. Thsi is new constant : read **Eitas** from right to left ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That should have been obvious. Thanks. The “UFO’s as given by NASA” is still not.

Comment: @TymaGaidash. When I saw the question, I started laughting and then my (stupid) joke. In a comment to you, I wrote that I used the same cryptography as when I was 4 or 5. Then the problem started to be fascinating when I found the simplest formulation of it.  By the way, I went to your website and downloaded the book about origami. Cheers